# SQL Server 2012, Inserting null when value less than 0

Tags: c#, .net, sql

In my .NET 4.5, C# application, I'm inserting 90 plus values into a row in SQL Server 2012. Some of the values are inserted into a 'float' column. However, some of the source values for this 'float' column are less than 0. On these particular columns, I need to insert a null into the column, or NOT insert into the column at all.

Any suggestions on how to best accomplish this.

I've tried using a SqlParameter with a type of Variant, and converting the value to 'object', but this can't be the best solution.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to insert these values.

Comment: Could you please share the sql script for inserting?

Comment: You need to use `DBNull.Value` to insert a null value.  When you set the value of a `SqlParameter`, it already takes type `object` regardless of the parameter's defined type, so you can seamlessly set it to either a float value or `DBNull`.

Comment: Is the task to fix the value inserted *at* the C# end (so the server never sees negative values) or at the SQL Server side?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (FloatColumn)
SELECT CASE TestValue
          WHEN FloatColumn<0 THEN NULL ELSE TestValue
       END
FROM SourceTable
```

Comment: Don't you need an `END` there?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger.

See the following article on MSDN for examples.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=SQL.105).aspx

> INSTEAD OF INSERT triggers can be defined on a view or table to
>   replace the standard action of the INSERT statement.

This trigger would be fired on the insert, and your logic can detect the values and take appropriate action, like inserting null into that field if the value is less than 0.

Comment: This really seems like the type of solution that will get lost and undocumented, and somebody will be debugging years later, trying to figure out why their negative number is silently being dropped.

Comment: Like I said, it's an option, or a tool to have in your belt. If you don't do much db development, then yes, you might have trouble tracking it down. If it is part of normal process then you would not have trouble tracking it down.

Answer (score 0):

A little extension method hung of C#'`s floating-point types should do you nicely whilst you build the parameter list for your SQL call:

```
public static SqlParameter PositiveOrNullSqlParameter( this float value , string name )
{
    return PositiveOrNullSqlParameter( (double) value , name ) ;
}
public static SqlParameter PositiveOrNullSqlParameter( this double value , string name )
{
    SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter( name , System.Data.SqlDbType.Float ) ;
    p.Value = ( value > 0 ? (object) value : (object) DBNull.Value ) ;
    return p ;
}
```

Once you have that...

```
int insertDataIntoMyTable( double p1 , double p2 , ... , double p99 )
{
    int rowcount ;
    string connectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ "MyConnectionString" ].ConnectionString ;

    using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(  ) )
    using ( SqlCommand    cmd  = conn.CreateCommand() )
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insertDataIntoTable" ;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;

        cmd.Parameters.Add( p1.PositiveOrNullSqlParameter( "@p01" ) ;
        cmd.Parameters.Add( p2.PositiveOrNullSqlParameter( "@p02" ) ;
        .
        .
        .
        cmd.Parameters.Add( p99.PositiveOrNullSqlParameter( "@p99" ) ;

        rowcount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ;

    }

    return rowcount ;
}
```